# How to make an image round and smaller when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want an image to become round and smaller when scrolling down my page.

At the beginning, the image should fill the whole page and while scrolling down I want the image to become smaller with increasing rounded borders.

So far, I have tried the following code:

html:

```
  <div class="image-container">
    <canvas id="moving-background-to-phone">
  </div>
```

css:

```
.image-container{
    min-height: 20000px;  /*temporary min-height*/
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;

}

#moving-background-to-phone{
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 66.667%;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-size: cover;

    background-image: url(../img/runningPerson.jpg);
    background-position: 0 1025px;
}
```

javascript:

```
 var $window = $(window);
    
    $window.scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
     if(scrollTop >= 0 && scrollTop < 1770) {
            $(document).on('scroll',function(){
              $("#moving-background-to-phone").css("position", "sticky");
              $("#moving-background-to-phone").css("border-radius", 0 + "px");
            })
          } else 
          if(scrollTop >= 1800 && scrollTop < 3000) {
            $(document).on('scroll',function(){
              $("#moving-background-to-phone").css("position", "fixed");
              $("#moving-background-to-phone").css("border-radius", Math.min(Math.floor(0.3*window.scrollY/2) + 1, 1500) + "px");
            })
          } else 
          if(scrollTop >= 2200 && scrollTop < 20000) {
            $(document).on('scroll',function(){
              $("#moving-background-to-phone").css("width", Math.min(Math.floor(0.3*window.scrollY/2) + 1, 3000) + "px");
              $("#moving-background-to-phone").css("height", Math.min(Math.floor(0.3*window.scrollY/2) + 1, 3000) + "px");
            })
          }
```

At the end I want the image to be just an icon of another image.
The other image is the following:

[image: result Image]

With the increasingly smaller image being the running person in top of the phone.

Currently, my problem is that as the image becomes smaller the image stays at the left of my page. But, I want the image to become smaller while still being centered.
The problem is caused by top: 0 in #moving-background-to phone. I could move the image by adding left or right, but I don't think that this would be an ideal solution.

Additionally here is a demo with some random pictures from Unsplash.com:
https://codepen.io/tobiasooo/pen/GRrEZvo?editors=1100

Similar questions:

- [How to make image size change smoothly on scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60431903/how-to-make-image-size-change-smoothly-on-scroll)
- [How to shrink an image width based on scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907050/how-to-shrink-an-image-width-based-on-scroll-position)

Comment: It would be good if you can create a working demo through external site like Codesandbox or Stackblitz

Comment: Do you realize your ranges make no sense? They overlap or have gaps?

Comment: The ranges overlap because I want the image the become round and smaller at the same time. Probably it would be better to not use if else statements in this context.

Additionally I will try to make an external demo.

Comment: The image stays at the right of the page?

Comment: Refer to this [How to shrink an image width based on scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907050/how-to-shrink-an-image-width-based-on-scroll-position) and [How to make image size change smoothly on scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60431903/how-to-make-image-size-change-smoothly-on-scroll)